# Learning Data(base) Modelling - Start-up Guidance

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

I would like to learn database modelling. I don't have an exposure to database modelling yet, though I worked on Database Application development on Oracle DB (I know relationship between business model and database model and how a product database supports the business model).
It would be so kind of you, if you can direct me on the right path to *learn database modelling from the scratch*.
My approach to this would be -

1. My current level of understanding on basics of Data Modelling.
2. Learning the basics and refresh the known items.
3. Learning the intermediate and building sample data model and experience the challenge.

To follow the above mentioned approach, I require the following details. -

1. A tool to measure my current level of understanding on (basics of) Data Modelling.
2. A good place to start learning the database modelling. (A website / A recommended book / A good video tutorial(free is the best option!))
3. A decent data model exercise probably with answers / suggestions so that I can realise my effort.

Please let me know if either the approach or details are not up to the level for a starter, and guide me on the same.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question as written is too broad. I would suggest that you visit the dba site http://dba.stackexchange.com and ask something like "How do I measure my knowledge of Data Modelling.

Comment: Here's as good a place to start as any. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: Thanks! This is a really the place to start with, for database modelling, as I followed it. It would be great if you can also direct me to a source of database modelling in particular?

Comment: For operational relational databases: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization  I learned this quip in data modelling school.  I solemnly swear that the data is dependent on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key, so help me Codd.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: Thanks, Gilbert. And yeah, May _Codd_ help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to take this course at Stanford (free, online): http://db.class2go.stanford.edu

Similar course is available at coursera (free, online): https://www.coursera.org/course/db

You did not mention, for what purpose you would like to learn database modelling. If data warehousing is is also on your list of skills, you should consider the following books:

- Agile Data Warehouse Design: Collaborative Dimensional Modeling, from Whiteboard to Star Schema
- The Data Warehouse Toolkit: The Complete Guide to Dimensional Modeling (Second Edition)
- Star Schema The Complete Reference

Comment: Thanks for the link! It seems that this is going to be whole new chapter for my learning thirst. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.sqlcourse.com/index.html) is a good site to get you started

After you get a fundamental overview of databases, I recommend going over to SQL Zoo to get your hands dirty:

http://sqlzoo.net/

Comment: While I agree it's a good site to learn **SQL**, it does not cover database *modelling*. So it isn't really an answer to the question.